# Web Scraper (Python 3.6) crashes when encountering javascript in string

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, crash

I coded a (probably inefficient) web scraper with BeautifulSoup for this [website](http://www.poliscirumors.com). While it works, the function to get the posts crashes when encountering a post that contains javascript as the loop that goes through the post content (`for item in i.find_all("p")[1:]:`) stops and a later request for meta data (`i.select('span')[0].get_text()`) of the post is unable to find the particular element. An example is the last post [here](http://www.poliscirumors.com/topic/tenure-denial-blog/page/23). While I could code an exception, I would prefer to understand the problem and solve it directly. What am I doing wrong?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests as rs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re
from itertools import chain
posts = []
def post_data(postlist, weblink, rmin, rmax):
    page = rs.get(weblink)
    soup = BS(page.content, 'lxml')
    for d in range(rmin, rmax):
        for i in soup.find_all("div", id="position-"+str(d)):
            text = []
            for item in i.find_all("p")[1:]:
                text.append(item.get_text().replace("\n" , "/" ).replace("," , "$" ))
            text = "".join(text)
            text.replace("\n", "/").replace("," , "$" )
            postlist.append((weblink, str(d), i.find("strong").get_text() , text , i.select('span')[0].get_text(), i.select('span')[1].get_text(), i.span["id"][1:], list(i.find("div", class_="poststuff"))[0]))
    postlist=list((chain.from_iterable(postlist)))
post_data(posts, "http://www.poliscirumors.com/topic/tenure-denial-blog/page/23", 460, 461)
```

The error is the following:

```
File "p3.py", line 20, in post_data
postlist.append((weblink, str(d), i.find("strong").get_text() , text , i.select('span')[0].get_text(), i.select('span')[1].get_text(), i.span["id"][1:], list(i.find("div", class_="poststuff"))[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

### try always ##then debug later

try:
    postlist.append((weblink, str(d), i.find("strong").get_text() , text , i.select('span')[0].get_text(), i.select('span')[1].get_text(), i.span["id"][1:], list(i.find("div", class_="poststuff"))[0]))

except:
       pass

Comment: Oh thanks. Lesson noted. Of course, this works. Though do you have an idea of why it crashes?

Comment: Anything rendered inside a javascript has given me tuff time. I had to retrieve to json response with the link I was working. Hope some more wise head see this post. Cheers